# Add border to UIImage to fit frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage, crop

I have a problem and can't come up with a solution. I want to add a border so my image will fit a specific size. I can't use UIImageView and set the content mode, because I will upload the final image to a server, so if I use setContentMode I will lose every changes.

An example of what I need is: My image is (200px X 400px), I need to add a border of 100px at the right and left side of the image, so the final size is (400px X 400px) without losing any content of the image.

Thanks

Comment: Why not separating the Presentation from the actual image data ?

Comment: so basically you need to resize the image to 400X400 proportionally ?

Comment: I need to keep to image content size and add some border

Comment: Put he UIImage in UIImageView, set the UIImageView frame to the desired size and color and raster the UIImageView to a new bitmap.